# How to add gke node pool as backend to http loadbalancer in gcp

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-http-load-balancer

I tried with NEG but it has limitations to only point to zonal cluster.however i have regional cluster so want to point the node pool as backend to http loadbalancer.how can i do that?